# Running a servlet in intelliJ from .java class, not .jsp

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to create and run a servlet in IntelliJ. The problem I'm having is I'm following an Eclipse tutorial and they seem to work very differently. In Eclipse, a servlet.java class is created and run on Tomcat. In IntelliJ a .java class and .jsp file is created. The browser points to .jsp, not .java. The java class doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.

Why are they so different, and how can I point to the .java class instead of the .jsp?

I've added the .java and .jsp code below, which are both the standard stubs created by IntelliJ when creating a new servlet project.

```
@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "The Tomcat server does not point to this code in IntelliJ";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Tomcat points to this .jsp file, not the .java code" %>
</h1>
<br/>
<a href="hello-servlet">Hello Servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The servlet class has an annotation indicating what URI to use, so whatever URL your application is accessed using, followed by `/hello-servlet`.

Kind of weird that they generate these files that'll be useless 99% of the time.